# How to End one Java Program and start another on an event

Tags: java, class, events

I am trying to make a game. I made a ready screen, and two "READY" buttons. I hooked up a separate `onClick` event to both buttons and they both turn green when it's clicked, and changes its text to "I'm Ready" However, I don't know how to start the next JAVA program when both of these buttons have turned green and read"I'm  Ready"

Comment: Starting a whole new program is probably not what you want.  What do you expect to happen for the user when both buttons are clicked?

Comment: Why start another program, rather than just running code specific to how you want your program to react to the event?

Comment: I expect for the user for another class to run. The title at the top will say to click as fast as they can, like cookie clicker, and I will add another event for them to swipe.

Comment: I can't add the thing into an event, for it should only work when both players click ready

Comment: So? In onClick check if both are ready and go on only if they are ... I don' t see what is stopping you ...

Comment: It is two separate onclick event things. If I put it into both, it would run two. Just to get it understood, you are saying to copy paste the entire game script and put it into the things that would happen when clicked, right.

Comment: Exactly, but after triggering the event, why should the other fire? To my understanding it goes like this: Button1->onclick-> setReady(1), checkbothReady->No. Then Button2->onclick->setReady(2), checkbothReady->yes -> Trigger Gamestart or whatever. After game Button state is reset, right? You could even use the same eventhandler. Depends on how you check for state of the button.